# Why does the upper component of a $SU(2)$ doublet has $T^3=1/2$ and lower component $T^3=-1/2$ and not the opposite?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, group-theory, representation-theory, isospin-symmetry

For a $SU(2)$ doublet, why does the upper component have $T^3=1/2$ and lower component $T^3=-1/2$?

I know that this can be answered in the Standard Model by using $Q=T^3+Y/2$. But that is because we choose to keep the neutrino $\nu_e$ in the upper component and electron $e$ in the lower component of the weak isospin doublet.

Could we have done the reverse i.e., assign $T^3=-1/2$ for the upper component and $T^3=+1/2$ lower component (and by exchanging $\nu_e$ and $e$ positions)? Or is it that irrespective of the relation $Q=T^3+Y/2$, the upper component the doublet has $T^3=1/2$ and lower have $T^3=-1/2$?

Comment: Why do we choose the upper part in an x,y plot to be positive and the lower negative? Why do we do that in general in all plots, put the negative y below the x axis and the negative x on the left of the y axis?

Comment: @annav That's a convention. Right? My question is exactly that i.e. whether or not it is a convention for SU(2) doublets.

Comment: my impression is that it is a convention,we tend to put positive higher than negative.

Answer (score 2):

A possible 2 dimensional representation of $SU(2)$ is the one for which

$$T_3 = \frac{1}{2}\sigma_3= \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)$$

In this representation is obvious that the top component is the $+1/2$ and the bottom component is $-1/2$. Since we like to use Pauli matrices, this is the most commonly used representation, but nothing is stopping you to consider a representation for which the top component is $-1/2$ and the bottom is $+1/2$. You just need to go to an equivalent representation for which $T_3$ is

$$T'_3 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc} -1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$$

And you get to this new representation by a similarity transformation

$$T'_3=U T_3 U^T$$

where

$$U = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$$